CSS scrolling table affects all tables in Quarto document
I have a Quarto document with multiple tables throughout it. I have been using R for the entire document but I wanted one table (gt package) to be scrollable so after some research, I added in the below code using CSS to achieve that:
gt() %>%
tab_options(
   table.width = "1000px",  # Set table width
    table.additional_css = "
      tbody {
        display: block;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        max-height: 400px;  
      }
      thead, tbody tr {
        display: table;
        width: 700px;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
      "
  )

This worked great except that every table in the document was affected and became scrollable, which I do not want. I added the above code only to the code chunk of the one table I wanted to change, and despite playing around with the width size, it still seems to be a global command.
My current header for the document is:
format: 
  html: 
    embed-resources: true
    toc: true
    code-fold: true
    code-tools: true

Do I need to add a global command to the header? I haven't used CSS before this but I can't find a fix online. Thanks in advance!

One option to fix your issue would be to add an id= to the table which allows to target the CSS modifications to the desired table ony:
---
format: html
---

```{r}
library(gt)
```


:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="40%"}

```{r}
#| echo: false
gt(gtcars, id = "scroll") |> 
  tab_options(
    table.additional_css = "
      #scroll tbody {
        display: block;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        max-height: 400px;
      }
      #scroll thead, tbody tr {
        display: table;
        width: 700px;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
      "
  )
```

:::


::: {.column width="20%"}

:::

::: {.column width="40%"}

```{r}
#| echo: false
gtcars |> 
  head(10) |> 
  gt()
```

:::

::::



Thank you for the suggestion! For some reason that isn't working though - do I need to specify an id for each table? With the current method, only the targeted table has a vertical scrollbar, but every table in the document receives a horizontal scrollbar and the column widths are messed up and stretched out as it tries to match the targeted table.
